# Nonlinear boundary value problem with Newton's Iteration

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the nonlinear two-point boundary value problem:

$-u''(t)+u(t)^p=\phi(t)$  ($0\leq t\leq 1$, $p\geq 2$ and $\phi\in C[0,1]$ is given function)

$u(0)=u(1)=0$

Given the following information:

(a) $u(t)=\int_{0}^{1} G(t,\xi)(\phi(\xi) - u(\xi)^p)d\xi$, $G(t,\xi)=\xi(1-t)$ if $0\leq \xi\leq t\leq 1$ and $G(t,\xi)=t(1-\xi)$ if $0\leq t\leq \xi\leq 1$)

(b) $(f(u))(t) = u(t) + \int_{0}^{1} G(t,\xi)(-\phi(\xi) + u(\xi)^p)d\xi$

(c) $f'(u)v = v+ p\int_{0}^{1}G(t,\xi)u(\xi)^{p-1}v(\xi)d\xi$ ($v\in C[0,1]$)

**Problem:** Show that given the kth Newton iterate $u_k$, finding the (k+1)st iterate $u_{k+1}$ is equivalent to solving:

$-u''(t) + p(u_{k}(t))^{p-1}u(t) = (p-1)(u_{k}(t))^{p} -\phi(t)\ \ (*)$

$u(0)=u(1)=0$

**My Attempt:** Since the Newton iterate is: $u_{k+1}=u_{k} - (f'(u_k))^{-1}f(u_k)$, we have:

$f(u_k)=f'(u_k)(u_k-u_{k+1})\ (1)$

Using the definitions of $f(u)$ and $f'(u)$, we have:

$f(u_k)=u_k+\int_{0}^{1} G(t,\xi)(-\phi(\xi) + u_{k}(\xi)^p)d\xi$

$f'(u_k)(u_k-u_{k+1}) = u_k-u_{k+1} + p\int_{0}^{1}G(t,\xi)u(\xi)^{p-1}(u_{k}(\xi)-u_{k+1}(\xi))d\xi$

Thus, from $(1)$, we have: $u_{k+1}(t)= p\int_{0}^{1}G(t,\xi)u_{k}(\xi)^{p-1}(u_{k}(\xi)-u_{k+1}(\xi))d\xi - \int_{0}^{1} G(t,\xi)(-\phi(\xi) + u_{k}(\xi)^p)d\xi$

Despite my countless hours spent, I couldn't proceed anywhere further from here in order to obtain $(*)$. Can someone please help me on this problem??